# ¿Como puedo obtener el dato de un array?

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de obtener el dato de un array pero no puedo acceder al indice de este array

```
 string s = "https://20.85.239.243:50000/b1s/v1/Orders(26)";

 String[] numeroOrden = s.Split('(');

 foreach (String numeroOrdens in numeroOrden)
 {
 String[] numOrden = numeroOrdens.Split(')');
 foreach (String datos in numOrden)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(datos);
    
 }

 }
```

La Respuesta de este codigo me da

https://.85.239.243:50000/b1s/v1/Orders

26

Necesito obtener el dato 26

Comment: No tienes que recorrer el array:
`String[] numeroOrden = s.Split('(',')');
Console.WriteLine(numeroOrden[1]);`

Comment: si eso mismo hice gracias por el dato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
string str = "https://20.85.239.243:50000/b1s/v1/Orders(26)";
int inicio = str.IndexOf("(") + 1;
int final = str.IndexOf(")");
int longitud = final - inicio;
string resultado = str.Substring(inicio , longitud);
```

En la **variable inicio** almacenas el índice donde se encuentra el **caracter "("**, en la **variable final** almacenas el índice donde se encuentra el **caracter ")"**, para esto haces uso de la **función IndexOf** posteriormente en la **variable longitud** almacenarías el tamaño del texto a copiar, y finalmente usando la **función Substring** extraerías de la cadena original la subcadena que deseas.

Answer (score 1):

Encontre esta forma de hacerlo es algo mas repetitivo pero también funciona

```
 string s = "https://20.85.239.243:50000/b1s/v1/Orders(26)";
 var orden = string.Empty;

 char delimitar = '(';

 string[] valores = s.Split(delimitar);

 Console.WriteLine(valores[1]);

 orden = valores[1];

 char delimitar2 = ')';

 string [] valores2 = orden.Split(delimitar2);

 Console.WriteLine(valores2[0]);
```